# Exception when embedding Web Content in a custom liferay portlet

Tags: plugins, classloader, liferay-6, portlet, apache-commons

I am embedding web content into a custom portlet deployed to Liferay EE 6.1 GA 1 using:

```
<liferay-ui:journal-article   articleId="REMEMBER"  groupId="<%=portletGroupId%>" />
```

This error started showing in the logs and the web content was not there:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1509)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
    at org.apache.jsp.html.taglib.ui.journal_005farticle.page_jsp._jspService(page_jsp.java from :410)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:71)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:807)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:671)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:626)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:556)
    at com.liferay.taglib.util.IncludeTag.include(IncludeTag.java:323)
    at com.liferay.taglib.util.IncludeTag._doInclude(IncludeTag.java:418)
    at com.liferay.taglib.util.IncludeTag.doEndTag(IncludeTag.java:92)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.askaquestion.askAQuestion_jsp._jspService(askAQuestion_jsp.java from :309)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that seems to help.  Updated the WEB-INF/liferay-plugin-package.properties to contain the line:

`portal.dependency.jars=commons-logging.jar,commons-fileupload.jar`

From https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+Developer+Cookbook :

> If there are any jar files which are already present in portal\WEB-INF\lib  and you also want to use them in your plugin.
>   Don't package those jars again  instead just add the reference in
>   `docroot\WEB-INF\liferay-plugin-package.properties`.

Answer (score 2):

please refer to the following URL:
http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+UI+Taglib

journal-article parameters:

```
articleId = uniqueID of content article
groupId = group of user
showTitle = show title of article true or false
templateId = which of the defined templates for this journal article to use. Note that there is a bug (reported here) in liferay versions before 6.0.2 where templateId is ignored.
```

example : 
< liferay-ui:journal-article articleId="22745" groupId="<%=scopeGroupId%>" />

Comment: Thanks for the link to the wiki.  However, it does not address the ClassNotFoundException at all and that was the real question.  Once that was solved the Web Content display worked using the tag I showed.

Answer (score 0):

Smith,
I have created the custom portlet and added one web content in jsp below is the code,also in plugin-package.properties I have added the tld files which all is used in JSP page and didn't added any jar file in properties file.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/theme" prefix="liferay-theme" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/ui" prefix="liferay-ui" %>
<portlet:defineObjects />
<liferay-theme:defineObjects/>

<liferay-ui:journal-article articleId="11414" articleResourcePrimKey="11416" groupId="<%=themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId() %>" languageId="<%=themeDisplay.getLanguageId() %>" showAvailableLocales="<%=true %>" ></liferay-ui:journal-article>
```

I have used the latest version of liferay 6.1.1 EE GA2,but I have verified it over the  LR6.1 EE GA1 it's working fine over there also.

Comment: Thanks for the example.  We are not sure why it stopped working for us.  We have received several hot fixes from Liferay for other issues and it may have been one of them. Making the small change in the `liferay-plugin-package.properties` seems like the right thing to do.  Although I never did trace it far enough to determine which class used by journal_article.jsp depends on the FileItemFactory.